# Issue with repeating image in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have view which should show the winner in the middle, I want to add bottom zigzag border, so far so good. Only issue I have when I add the image and make it fitXY it only repeats until middle of view (TableRow). Any idea how to make it to do it full screen?

Here is the winner.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/winner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/red_transparent"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="field"
        android:weightSum="9" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/zigzag_bottom" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/winner_logo"
                    android:layout_width="50sp"
                    android:layout_height="50sp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/back"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/vertical" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/winner_info"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/winner_logo"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/back"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/horizon"
                    android:text="@string/winner"
                    android:textColor="#880000"
                    android:textSize="64sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="12dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/zigzag_bottom" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the repeatable image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:src="@drawable/zigzagdown"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found issue

android:stretchColumns="field"

should be android:stretchColumns="*", so it will stretch all columns